# Magento - How to set timezone in date field of PHP?

Tags: php, magento, date, timezone

I have one date field in `Form.php` as below:

```
$fieldset->addField('trigger_time', 'date', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('order_test')->__('Trigger Time'),
            'name'  => 'trigger_time',
            'title' => Mage::helper('order_test')->__('Trigger Time'),
            'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
            'time' => true,
        ));
```

Take my locale timezone `GMT+2` for example. If I input `2015-08-29 12:00:00` in the form, what I want to save in database is `2015-08-29 10:00:00`, while currently my Magento's behavior is saving what exactly I input.

Would like to save the trigger_time using `GMT` time in database even if I input the local time in the form. Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$fieldset->addField('trigger_time', 'date', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('order_test')->__('Trigger Time'),
            'name'  => 'trigger_time',
            'title' => Mage::helper('order_test')->__('Trigger Time'),
            'image' => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL),
            'time' => true,
        ));
```

Comment: I tried it before but it didn't work. It's just making difference on time format. What's more, I indeed need that format. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out finally.

```
$store_timezone = new DateTimeZone(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/timezone'));
$gmt_timezone = new DateTimeZone('Etc/GMT');
   if (isset($template[$key]) && trim($template[$key]) != '') {
      $dateTime = new DateTime($template['base_time'], $gmt_timezone);
      $dateTime->setTimezone($store_timezone);
      $template['base_time'] = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   }
```

I placed these codes in saveAction method of my controller. It would retrieve the locale timezone and convert the input to GMT time before saving into database.